# Docker : node.js container proxy rest api to .net core 2.1 container

Tags: express, docker, asp.net-core

Power of stack overflow i believe in you! :)

[I have 2 containers in docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3vOF.png)

- 1 node.js express (it's client angular 6 with server render) with proxy "http-proxy-middleware" to .net core web api (linked to .net core container)

  ```
  import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
  import 'reflect-metadata';
  import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
  import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
  import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
  import * as express from 'express';
  import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
  import * as cors from 'cors';
  import * as compression from 'compression';
  import * as proxy from 'http-proxy-middleware';
  import {join} from 'path';
  enableProdMode();

  export const app = express();

  app.use(compression());
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(proxy('http://server/api'));

  const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');

  app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }));

  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.set('views', './dist/browser');

  app.get('/redirect/**', (req, res) => {
    const location = req.url.substring(10);
    res.redirect(301, location);
  });

  app.get('*.*', express.static('./dist/browser', {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {req, res}, (err, html) => {
      if (html) {
        res.send(html);
      } else {
        console.error(err);
        res.send(err);
      }
    });
  });
  ```
- 2 .net core 2.1 webapi

  ```
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
  using MongoDB.Driver;
  using Server.Models;
  using AutoMapper;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
  using MongoDB.Bson;
  using System;

  namespace Server.Api {
      [Route("api/test")]
      public class TestApi : Controller {

          [HttpGet]
          public string get() {
              return "api works";
          }

          [HttpPost]
          public Login Post([FromBody]Login value) {
              return value;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

when i make get request from node.js container to second i get result and no errors,
but when i make post request i get [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBtdf.png)

As I understood this problem caused by FromBody in .net core, because when I delete it there are no errors, but the data in the request also does not.

Help please!!! What i am doing wrong ? :(

Comment: Please do not post code on images and for non-code images upload it to stackoverflow and not to external websites (they may become unavailable in future). post and format the code inside the question

Comment: @Tseng Thank for your remark, fix that :)